# PHP imagecreatefrompng stops the code without any exception

Tags: php, png

I want to use the method `imagecreatefrompng` in my php code. Before calling this method I have checked that the path is referring to a file and the mime type is `image/png` these are my watches:

[image: evidence of correct file]

But as I try this method `$this->image = imagecreatefrompng($bg);` the running code stops without any exception:

```
try {
        $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($bg);
        $this->colour = ImageColorAllocate($this->image, 0, 0, 0); // Black
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }
```

How can I check for error?

Comment: Yeah, those functions don't `throw` exceptions. Have you tried activating error reporting and/or checking your error logs instead?

Comment: Maybe imagecreatefrompng is returning FALSE (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) and then your are calling ImageColorAllocate with boolean as a first parameter which needs an image (in this case ImageColorAllocate will return NULL and a warning);

Comment: @deceze, yes. In that page I have activated error reporting and nothing outputted, so I suspected to the result being routed to the browser. So I have tested this in a simple php file and I got this message "Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng". So I just had to install gd library. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was all about gd library not being installed on my machine. So I have followed [this link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/) to install that and now every thing just goes fine.